# Rails iterate images in erb views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

So I had an error earlier and finally got it working but not the way it's suppose to. So users can create a post with pictures. When you go to show.html.erb all the pictures show up that belong to that post. When you go to index.html.erb to see all post created in the database, each post has a image, more like a thumbnail. The code i have below shows the thumbnail image but that image doesnt belong to that post.For example, the post on the right in the picture is suppose to be a red car, and the post on the left is suppose to be a blue car but it's not. The image on both post belongs to a whole different post.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhgJO.png)

```
                    <figure>
                      <div class="icon">
                        <i class="lni-heart"></i>
                      </div>
                      <% if post.image.attached? %>
                         <%= image_tag post.image, :class => 'img-fluid' %>
                      <% end %>
                    </figure>
```

Comment: can you share the whole html document with this view, and the controller method where the variables are created?

Answer (score -2):

`post.image` by itself is just the object. You need to specify the name attribute  of image or even the thumb

```
<%= image_tag post.image.name %>
```

or

```
<%= image_tag post.image.name.thumb %>
```